# JPA2 Many To Many Mapping

Tags: jpa-2.0, has-many

I have a special Many2Many to map in Hibernate JPA2.

There is RECIPE entity one one side and INGREDIENT entity on the other side.

If I would say RECIPE has many-2-many INGREDIENTS, that would be simple many-2-many mapping

I want to say RECIPE HAS 15 Ingredients (Tomatoes), 23 Ingredients (Apples) and 3 Ingredients (Oranges).

Not sure how to map something that looks like many 2 many but has a 3rd parameter: Quantity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need an additional entity:

Additional entity:

```
QuantifiedIngredient:
   - @ManyToOne Ingredient ingredient
   - int quantity
```

Modifed entity:

```
Recipe:
   - @OneToMany Set<QuantifiedIngredient> quantifiedIngredients
```

Comment: Tnx, I was thinking that intermediate entity with a complex pk (recipe_pk, ingredient_pk) and attribute qty, might be a viable solution.